# Single Application ROM for Android

Tags: android

I'm going to develop an android application and I need custom android ROM to prevent user of android device from exiting our application. All other functionality in the device should be disabled/blocked.

Custom ROM requires On start up run 1 application and 1 service.

I know about custom ROM and how to modify it, i just wanna ask is it possible to add script for doing this? and how I find a way to develope this script?

Comment: Have you found a rom with your spec or similar?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of applications that you can use to lock down a device, without having to build your own ROM.

Some examples:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsi.kioware.client.mobile.app

Or you could follow a process like this:

https://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/